# Laravel Scheduling conflicts with multiple calls

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, scheduling

I am using Laravel [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling)

I need to run multiple tasks at different times, like this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\SomeController@job1')->daily();
    $schedule->call('App\Scheduled\SomeClass@job2')->hourly();
    $schedule->call('App\Scheduled\SomeClass@job3')->hourly();
    $schedule->call('App\Scheduled\SomeOtherClass@job4')->daily();
}
```

But for some reason everything runs once a day (at 12:00am). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like your cron job is only running `artisan schedule:run` once per day.  Make sure your cron job is set up like the docs:

`* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

The `* * * * *` part means run every minute, and then Laravel will decide which tasks to run each minute based on your schedule.

Comment: That's the first thing I checked, it is every minute.

Comment: And if you add a test command at the top that just logs something, do you see that log every minute?  Is it possible there is an error in one of the commands?

Comment: You were correct, I was allowing an exception to bubble up all the way to this function. Thanks!